# Need to get the ID value of sub-element in protractor

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, webautomation

I am trying to automate test case using Protractor and Jasmine. The problem is I have an "article" web element tag that gets created at runtime and this web-element has a  as sub element. This div element has a "id" tag associated with it. The structure of the code is below.

`<article class="a b c d" data-ng-repeat="xyz repeat">
<div id="THIS IS WHAT I WANT" class="class name">
</article>`

Now I am able to get get hold of the article web-element. but I am not able to get the ID attribute in the div. The ID values is generated dynamically. Kindly suggest how I can get the ID value.

Thank you

Comment: If you can get the element without the ID, why do you need the ID?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a CSS Selector like this:

```
article > div
```

This will get you a div inside of an article. Now you can use this to play around and specify the selector further with classes or other stuff.
If you managed to get the div element you can then pull out the idea using (not sure if the syntax is correct but you should get the idea):

```
element.getAttribute('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1) element(by.xpath(//div[@class='class name'])).getAttribute('id')

2) element(by.xpath(//article [@class='abcd']//div[@id='THIS IS WHAT I WANT'])).getAttribute('id')
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chains like this:

```
element(by.classname('')).element(by.className('classname'));
or
element(by.css('css of parent')).element(by.css('child css'));
```

or you can use `element(by.repeater('repeat in reapeats')).element(by.css(''));`